# styling hover state of a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, hover

I am attempting to style a hover state of a variable I have created. I'm pretty new to javascript, so hopefully one of you can help me out.

here is the script:

```
controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

var controlUI = document.createElement('DIV');
controlUI.style.height = '19px';
controlUI.style.backgroundColor = '#F9F9F9';
controlUI.style.background = 'linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#f3f3f3 50%,#ededed 51%,#ffffff 100%)';
controlUI.style.boxShadow = '2px 2px 2px 1px #999';
controlUI.style.borderRadius = '2px';
controlUI.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
controlUI.style.borderWidth = '1px';
controlUI.style.borderColor = '#9BADCF';
controlUI.style.cursor = 'pointer';
controlUI.style.textAlign = 'center';
controlUI.title = 'Click Me';
controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
```

what I am wanting to do is to write script to set different style properties for the div created by the variable controlUI, when the mouse hovers over said div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are working purely with JavaScript, instead of with CSS, you will need to do this the hard way, namely with events. With jQuery, it would be:

```
$(controlUI).hover(
    function onMouseEnter() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    },
    function onMouseLeave() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#F9F9F9";
    }
);
```

Without jQuery, you would need to use DOM events, which is a pain because they are not cross-browser compatible with IE less than 9, as [discussed extensively in this MDC article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener). The code ends up looking something like:

```
var crossBrowserAEL = controlUI.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";

controlUI[crossBrowserAEL]("mouseover", function () {
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
});
controlUI[crossBrowserAEL]("mouseout", function () {
    controlUI.style.backgroundColor = "#F9F9F9";
});
```

Answer (score 4):

### Try to avoid setting inline styles

Setting inline styles is very bad practice because it's hard to maintain while you have to look inside code to decipher where certain styles are set. I'm not even trying to touch browser differences that may become a real pain if you'll be using pure DOM+Javascript.

### A better approach: use CSS classes

Instead of setting particular individual styles on your created element (and writing several lines of code) it's much simpler and better to just apply a CSS class to your element:

```
controlDiv.className = "some-class";
```

and then define everything about this class in the CSS file that defines all styles. This will also make it very simple to define related styles (like hover, visited, ::before etc.)